# Graylog search contains string

Tags: regex, search, graylog2

I need to search in my data, which is *apache2* log, I need all requests which URL is like so:

```
http://*&ucode=jn04
```

It starts with `http` and ends with `&ucode=jn04`

I tried this query :

```
http_referer:"http*&ucode=jn04"
```

but it doesn't work, and it gives me all URLs which end with the number "4".

I'm using Graylog 2.4.6

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I finally found the answer and my query string which gives me true result is :

```
http_referer:/https.*jn04/
```